# Cannot register to firebase notifications on ios using ionic

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification

### Backstory:

Recently I have been working on a project using Ionic Framework v2 to develop applications both for Android and iOS. I had two fully working apps until I had to add push notifications functionality. Although the process of adding it to Android was pretty easy and it works, the iOS version is a real struggle.

For the Android I have installed phonegap-plugin-push and added @ionic-native/push package. To have this working I also had to update other packages in the project. To send push notifications to Android I ended up using Firebase platform, which now works just fine.

When I was trying to apply the same code for iOS, problems started to emerge. Because of the 1.10 version of phonegap-plugin-push I had to use CocoaPods to install it. Then `GoogleCloudMessaging 1.2.0` and `GGLInstanceID 1.2.1` pods were needed for the project to build (now I know that v.1.8 of phonegap-plugin-push does not require CocoaPods to work).

I have worked along the Firebase and Ionic guides, using .xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproject; I have added needed Pods and references to the project; I have enabled push notifications in the Capabilities settings of the app; I have generated appId, provisioning profile and certificates for push notifications (both for development and production) and uploaded them to the Firebase console; I have added `GoogleService_info.plist` file; I have set SENDER_ID in the project.

### Problem:

Despite all of the abovementioned steps the application does not receive push notifications. It looks like the registration process never succeeds as console logs from the success part of the `pushObject.on('registration')` method never shows up (it does not show errors either). The only error that I sometimes get is `com.google.gcm error 3004` when trying to subscribe or unsubscribe from topic (only one topic at a time). Sometimes I can see `registrationId` in the logs but when I try to send notification using this id, I get `"NotRegistered"` error.

I have also tried adding Firebase pods but it did not make any difference.

### Question:

Is it possible that push notifications on iOS 7.1 will not work in this environment, or is this problem connected with the Firebase settings and Apple's certificates (or something else)?

---

- iOS Version: 7.1.2
- XCode version: 7.3.1
- Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
- Node Version: 6.9.5
- Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
- Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
- @ionic-native/core Version: 3.4.4
- @ionic-native/push Version: 3.4.4